# ¿Cómo obtengo el resultado de un select en ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Dispongo de una vista, la cual, al seleccionar en un `<select>` anterior, varia su contenido y he de capturar que elemento está seleccionado.

Estoy usando el `Html.DropDownListFor` para obtener los datos en el primer `<select>` de la siguiente manera:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListaClases, new SelectList(Model.ListaClases, "IdClase", "Clase"), new { @class = "input form-control input-lg", @required = "required", @style = "height: 40px; font-size:16px" })
```

He de obtener en la misma vista y sin usar javascript, el valor que esta seleccionado para poder pintar el otro.

He probado a intentar generar un campo oculto `@Html.HiddenFor` e ir asignandole el valor con el evento *onChange* con algo parecido a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056508/onchange-event-for-html-dropdownlist) pero no he logrado realizarlo

¿Cómo puedo obtener el **`IdClase`** sin usar javascript y reflejarlo directamente en el Html?

**EDIT 1**

Para aclarar aun mas el asunto subo la vista como la tengo actualmente,
Comenzare por una captura del formulario:
[image: Formulario]

1. Tres inputs de tipo text, no generan ningún conflicto
2. Clase y subclase, dos Listas Vinculadas entre sí, la Clase es la que quiero obtener el id
3. Propiedades y Valor, estas han de variar dependiendo de la Clase(Actualmente funcionando en javascript)
4. Botones para añadir/eliminar las propiedades a la tabla
5. Botón Aceptar hace el submit del formulario

El Código de la ventana(cshtml):

```
    @model ArticuloVm
    @{
        /**/

        Layout = null;
        var variable = 1;
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

                Código
                <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="Codigo" id="Codigo" style=" height: 50px; font-size:21px;" autocomplete="off" value="@Model.Codigo">

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">

                Código Ean
                <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="CodigoEan" id="CodigoEan" style="height: 50px; font-size:21px;" autocomplete="off" value="@Model.CodigoEan">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>


        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">

                Descripción
                <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="Descripcion" id="Descripcion" style="height: 50px; font-size:21px;" autocomplete="off" value="@Model.Descripcion">

            </div>

        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                Clase
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListaClases, new SelectList(Model.ListaClases, "IdClase", "Clase"), new { @class = "input form-control input-lg", @required = "required", @style = "height: 40px; font-size:16px", onchange = variable++ }) 
                //probando si funcionaba el evento onchange para capturar la variable, con esta prueba he descubierto que tan solo lo ejecuta 1 vez poniendo el valor a 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                SubClase
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListaSubClases, new SelectList(Model.ListaSubClases, "IdClase", "Clase"), new { @class = "input form-control input-lg", @required = "required", @style = "height: 40px; font-size:16px" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>   
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                &nbsp;
            </div>      


            <div class="col-md-4">  

    //Actualmente puesto en dos selects, es lo que quiero transformar según el id de la Clase
                    <select class="input form-control input-lg" id="valor" name="valor"

 style="height: 40px; font-size:16px; position:absolute; visibility: hidden; width: 92%;">
                    <option value="1">Valor máximo</option>
                    <option value="2">Valor mínimo</option>
                </select>
                <select class="input form-control input-lg" id="Tiene" name="Tiene" style="height: 40px; font-size:16px; position:absolute; width: 92%;">
                    <option value="1">Tiene Solomillo</option>
                    <option value="2">Tiene rabo</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                Valor:
                <input style="height: 40px; width: 92%; font-size:18px; visibility: hidden;  position:absolute;" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Valor" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" autocomplete="off">
                <select class="input form-control input-lg" id="sino" name="sino" style="height: 40px; font-size:16px; position:absolute; width: 92%;">
                    <option value="1">Si</option>
                    <option value="2">No</option>
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-top: 1.5%;">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <button id="anadir" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Añadir</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <button disabled id="quitar" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Quitar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <br/>   
        <div class="row" style="overflow-y:scroll; height: 200px">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                <table id="Propiedades" class="display projects-table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Propiedad</th>
                            <th>Valor</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    }
```

En el momento que pulso el botón Aceptar salta al controlador y entra en la siguiente función:

```
        [TsVisible]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NuevoArticulo(ArticuloVm vm)
        {

            try
            {               
                Debug.WriteLine("Datos: " + vm.Codigo + ", " + vm.Descripcion + ", " + vm.CodigoEan + ", " + vm.ListaClases + ", " + vm.ListaSubClases);

                //_svcConfiguraciones.AnadirArticulo(vm.Codigo, vm.Descripcion, vm.CodigoEan, vm.Datos);
                return AjaxResp.Ok("Nuevo Articulo", "Articulo añadido correctamente");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Error(ex);
                return AjaxResp.Error("Nuevo Árticulo", "Se ha producido un error al añadir el árticulo");
            }

        }
```

Con la llamada a `_svcConfiguraciones` entraría a la clase encargada de gestionar la BD, bloqueada por razones obvias, resulta que el mensaje de debug me muestra los que si están definidos en la vista por el modelo pero no los que capturé por javascript/Jquery, el metodo que uso es:

```
$('#aceptarPost').click(function () {

mvc.Configuracion.NuevoArticulo.post({ Codigo: $('#Codigo').val(), CodigoEan: $('#CodigoEan').val(), Descripcion: $('#Descripcion').val() }, res => {        
    console.log("Respuesta");
});
});
```

Esta llamada actualmente solo estan tres de todos los parametros pero por pruebas anteriores que hice, estaban todos los valores definidos.

Comment: No termino de entender lo que buscas hacer cuando cambia el select, algo como comboboxes en cascada?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Si mas o menos, si tengo en uno "lechugas" quiero que en el otro me aparezcan los tipos de lechugas y si tengo "carne" salgan los tipos de carne

Comment: La idea es que al cambiar la página, se recargue en lugar de usar javascript?

Comment: Si, sin usar nada de javascript, de ahi viene todo mi problema

Comment: Creo que estas obligado a usar js, ya sea para modificar el dom, o para forzar el envío del formulario para procesar en el backend :s

Comment: estas navegando entre dos view? realizas un post desde una pagina y redireccionas a la siguiente

Comment: @LeandroTuttini No, no navego entre dos views

Comment: o sea ambos combos estan en la misma view? me temo que vas a tener que usar javascript, es mas seria mejor si usas jquery. Si habilitas esto podemos darte una respuesta, sino me temo que no hay solucion

Comment: @LeandroTuttini He aumentado el detalle, si necesitas algo mas o ves una solucion sera bienvenido

Comment: @NicolasOñate si podes agregate la definición de tu viewmodel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema se da porque estas usando incorrectamente [`Html.DropDownListFor()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_SelectExtensions_DropDownListFor__2_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Web_Mvc_SelectListItem__System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_Object__).

Recordá, que la expresión lambda que recibe como primer parámetro, es la que asociará el `<select>` con el name correspondiente a la propiedad, en tu caso, por ejemplo.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListaSubClases, new SelectList(Model.ListaSubClases, "IdClase", "Clase"), new { @class = "input form-control input-lg", @required = "required", @style = "height: 40px; font-size:16px" })
```

Tu primer parámetro hace referencia a `ListaSubClases` por lo que le asignará el `name` del `select` será `ListaSubClases`, de tal manera, en tu Controller intentará asociarlo con la propiedad `ListaSubClases` de tu modelo, y simplemente no podrá hacerlo porque es de un tipo distinto a `int`.

Para solucionarlo, lo que tendrías que hacer, es dentro de tu `ViewModel` tener un `int` donde recibas ese dato, por ejemplo

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public int ListaSubClasesId { get;set; }
    public List<T> ListaSubClases { get; set; }
}
```

`T` hace referencia al tipo de la lista que tenes almacenado en `ListaSubClases`

Luego, en la vista, quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListaSubClasesId, new SelectList(Model.ListaSubClases, "IdClase", "Clase"), new { @class = "input form-control input-lg", @required = "required", @style = "height: 40px; font-size:16px" })
```

De esta manera, a tu Controller, llegaría el `Id` del `select` en la propiedad `ListaSubClasesId` de tu ViewModel